# 4 x 2GB Crucial DDR3 not working with ASUS P8Z68-V LX mobo

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, ddr3

I cannot get all 4 of the Crucial memory sticks to boot inside the 4 slots of the ASUS P8Z68-V LX ATX Motherboard.  Only 2 - thus 4GB - will allow the boot, anymore and the red light shows.

Crucial's memory compatibility tool on their site said the ram would be compatible with the board. Why isn't the full 8GB working though? Software wise I'm dual booting Win7 and Debian but not even the bios will boot with 4 sticks in.

[This](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/p8z68-v-lx/CT2515646) is the RAM

Comment: Why down votes?

Comment: Does the system boot if you only have two sticks in?

Comment: @Sane Yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting only two sticks in at a time and swapping out one at a time to see if one of the sticks causes the system to fail to boot, if one does then you have a bad stick of RAM.

Comment: yeah the new ones work on their own too....

Comment: You are using two different kinds of memory, 2 original and 2 new?

Comment: yeah. Both same brand.

Comment: There are systems that don't like to play nice when you have two different kinds of ram, even if they are the same brand, in them. Also lots of systems have 2 ram slots of one color and 2 of another color, the ram of the same type should go into the same color (exp. on my MB it is black, blue, black, blue, so I'd put [old ram], [new ram], [old ram], [new ram])

Comment: I ordered the exact same type. But just in case I'll alternate with the black/blue scheme.

Comment: Tried alternate with black/blue but still no good. Would there be some reason for the board not supporting 4 sticks or 8GB?